# Show that we can check if $G$ has a circuit in time $O(V)$.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, algorithms

Consider a non-directed graph $G=(V,E)$ at which it is not allowed that we have edges of the form $(v,v)$. Show that we can check if $G$ has a circuit in time $O(V)$.

According to my notes, we can check if there is a circuit, applying  the Breadth-first-search algorithm. If a node is seen two times then we know that there is a circuit.

But isn't the time complexity of BFS equal to $O(V+E)$ ?

Furthermore, couldn't we also apply the Depth-first-search algorithm and check if there are back edges?

Comment: Well, if you just want to know if there's a cycle/circuit, you can say "Yes" whenever $|E| \geq |V|$.  Otherwise if $|E| < |V|$, you can do a Breadth-first-search in $O(|V|)$ time.  If you need to find an actual cycle though, this doesn't do it.

Answer (score 0):

Generally both BFS and DFS works in $O(V+E)$, but for your case, it can be made to work in $O(V)$ by immediately terminating upon finding/checking such cycle. BFS can be made to work, but it's less trivial than DFS, so I'll do the DFS one instead:

Do an ordinary DFS, but the first time you are going to add a node $v$ to the stack that is already in the stack, stop. All the nodes in the top of the stack above or equal (in depth) to $v$ form a cycle.